# WSO2 - Error while invoking APIUsageStatisticsClient for ProviderAPIUsage

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I have setup WSO2 API Manager (version 1.9.1) and have configured it with BAM (version 2.5.0) following the instructions provided here to the letter:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics

I am using MySQL server and can see the api_* tables created and getting updated as I make API calls. However, when I go to look at the statistics, I see an exception on the console, while the UI tells me that I need to configure BAM to see the dashboards.

Here is a snippet of the ERRORs seen in wso2carbon.log

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-11-19 11:27:39,110] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject} -  Error while invoking APIUsageStatisticsClient for ProviderAPIUsage {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.exception.APIMgtUsageQueryServiceClientException: Error occurred while querying from JDBC databasecom.mysql.jdbc.driver
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.APIUsageStatisticsClient.queryFirstAccess(APIUsageStatisticsClient.java:2762)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.APIUsageStatisticsClient.getFirstAccessTime(APIUsageStatisticsClient.java:2706)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.APIUsageStatisticsClient.queryFirstAccess(APIUsageStatisticsClient.java:2730)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
    ... 71 more
TID: [0] [AM] [2015-11-19 11:27:39,138] ERROR {JAGGERY.modules.statistics.usage:jag} -  java.lang.NullPointerException: null {JAGGERY.modules.statistics.usage:jag}
```

I have looked at other similar posts but nothing seems to be exactly relevant. The closest similar post had a SQL Server specific issue, but I am using MySQL.

Additional Information: I am running BAM and API Manager on the same machine. I have set offset on BAM to 3 as recommended in the guide.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you have not added the SQL connector to /repository/components/lib and /repository/components/lib folders. This is mentioned in the step 5 of https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics.

Make sure that the SQL connector is correctly placed on those locations

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar is present in both folders.

Comment: Do I need to explictly add it to the classpath?

Comment: Specified URL Content does not exist anymore, please update!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying above scenario in a Windows environment, please use "mysql-connector-java-5.1.30" connector and place it in  /repository/components/lib and /repository/components/lib folders. This could be due to a connector version problem.